# SMIE precedence conflict

Tags: indentation, smie

```
(defvar foo-smie-grammar
  (smie-prec2->grammar
   (smie-bnf->prec2
    '((exp (exp "+" exp)
           (exp "*" exp)
           ("let" let-decls "in" exp))
      (let-decls (let-decls ";" let-decls)
                 (exp)))
    '((assoc ";") (assoc "+") (assoc "*")))))
```

The above gives warnings:

```
Warning (smie): Conflict: in >/< *
Warning (smie): Conflict: in >/< +
Warning (smie): Total: 2 warnings
```

Without the `let-decls` non-terminal, all is fine.  How do I fix this?  The grammar isn't obviously problematic to me.

Comment: Since this is not common knowledge yet: you might like to read this paper that came out recently: https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~monnier/smie.pdf

Comment: Nice!  Thanks very much for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add an associativity level for `in`, making it weaker/looser than the other binary operators.  E.g., changing the last line to

```
    '((assoc "in") (assoc ";") (assoc "+") (assoc "*")))))
```

This is because the parser needs to be able to see that

```
  let e1 in e2 + e3
```

should be parsed as

```
  let e1 in (e2 + e3)
```

rather than

```
  (let e1 in e2) + e3
```